# How to add a custom response header to 404 and 500 page in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I want to add a custom response header to my 404 and 500 pages for Next.js app. I use a custom 404 page (as described [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#customizing-the-404-page)) and the default 500 page. I tried adding custom headers as described [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers), but that doesn't seem to work. Below is the `next.config.js` I added:

```
{
    source: '/404',
    headers: [
      { key: 'CDN-Cache-Control', value: '1' },
    ],
  },
  {
    source: '/500',
    headers: [
      { key: 'CDN-Cache-Control', value: '1' },
    ],
  },
```

Seemingly that isn't the correct way to specify source for all 404 responses. I do see the header appearing on localhost:3003/400, but it doesn't show up on any actual 404 response triggered by the Next.js router.

PS: The reason we want to cache the 404 and 500 for a small duration is prevent all requests to the same URL from hitting the server, and be served from the CDN edge instead.